# Understanding Belgium, Antwerp Police Immigration Index Numbers?

Tags: immigration, indexing, belgium

[image: Migration record for Majersdorf Elozor]

I am referring to the record marked with an arrow.

Can someone tell me what do the numbers or letters in parenthesis after his name and before his birth date mean ?

Also on the extracted info on the left they say "Other: 1916" - Can anyone guess where they took this year from and what does it mean?

B.T.W - Just for reference if anyone is specifically interested in this record - IMHO the middle name for this person should be "Mordeko" (from Hebrew Mordechai) and not "Morako" (I have a birth record for him somewhere else).

Comment: I am aware of this document. I am looking for some information regarding Mordeci's parents. Is Mordeci from Warsaw or Pultusk. I am trying to connect up different parts of the Majersdorf families. Chaim Meiersdorf

Comment: sure you are, we are sharing all our info :) (Eyal Peleg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The image shown in the question is from Ancestry's [Belgium, Antwerp Police Immigration Index, 1840-1930](http://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=9790). In the About section, one is directed to FamilySearch's wiki page, [Belgium, Antwerp, Police Immigration (FamilySearch Historical Records)](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Belgium,_Antwerp,_Police_Immigration_%28FamilySearch_Historical_Records%29)

1. According to the FamilySearch wiki page, only the locality appears between the name and the birthdate. I don't see numbers after Pultusk, I see (P-). Just above, it looks like (G-), perhaps added as a correction. Together G- P- = Gr. Po. = Groot-Polen [Dutch] = Greater Poland
2. Since the database includes the years 1840-1930, 1916 is probably the year your record was added. The image in the question does not include the headings, but the example image on the wiki page shows the page's year range. Perhaps this does not appear on every page, and you would have to browse backwards until you find the first page in the record sub-set. Alternatively, the image path descriptions may provide the date information.

Answer (score 3):

The number 195012 is the file number of the Antwerp Police Report. Go to FamilySearch.org and look under Europe and Belgium. There you will find documents that can be browsed. Click on it and you will get a long list of documents. Find the one that contains 195012 and browse it until you find the file 195012. It contains a gold mine of information.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the 2-minute [Tour] which is designed to introduce every user to the site and its protocols.  For example, I have edited your signature out of your answer because every post you make here is already signed by [your user card](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/users/5609/bob-heck).

Comment: can you please explain how am I supposed to "look under Europe and Belgium" ?

Comment: o.k. I managed to find the index of the files. it urns out the correct file number for my record of interest is 195612.
https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-L99C-LJN1?i=118&wc=M6T7-938%3A342126001%3Fcc%3D2023926&cc=2023926
Now I have some more docs to figure out what they mean :)